# Compatibility between iText 5.5.3 and java 1.6.0.17

Tags: java, oracle, itext

I want to do a loadjava of iText 5.5.3 on my database. My database is oracle 10.2.0.4, I think I have a problem of java version.

On my database it is:

```
C:\numerisation>java -version
java version "1.6.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_17-b04)
```

The first error I get when doing my load java is:

```
resolving: class com/itextpdf/text/pdf/hyphenation/CharVector
errors   : class com/itextpdf/text/pdf/hyphenation/CharVector
    ORA-29552: avertissement de vÚrification : java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
    com/itextpdf/text/pdf/hyphenation/CharVector (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)
```

I searched on the web and it says I have not a compatible version of java. What would you do ? Install a new version of Java on the database ? If yes, which one ? On the database it worked with iText 2.1.3.

Comment: Version 49 class files are generated by Java 5. That means that somewhere in your system, you have a version of Java older than Java 5. Find _that_, and upgrade it. Note, you can have multiple versions of Java installed on the same computer, so just because your default version is Java 6, does not mean that that's the version your Oracle is using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using load java, you are dependent on the version of the JVM inside the Oracle database not the version of the JVM installed on the server outside the database.  The fact that you have a 1.6 JVM outside the database doesn't help you.

Oracle 10.2 shipped with a 1.4 JVM.  Unfortunately, since it is bundled with the database, the internal JVM cannot be upgraded independently.  You could upgrade the entire database to 11.2 or to 12c (which would be good since 10.2 is in sustaining support these days).  Short of that, you would need an older version of iText that works with the older JVM or you would need to architect the system so that the iText code is running in the JVM outside the database.